# How to give different colors to set of rows in gsp table depending on values in fields?

Tags: grails, colors, gsp

I have gsp table, and I'm filling values in its fields from collection passed from controller using each tag of gsp for each row. Now I want rows which gets same value for billId field should get displayed in different color. How to do that?

Comment: Please post your existing code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following:

```
<g:each in="${billings}" status="i" var="billing">
<set var="cssClass" value"${(billing.id % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'}"/>
<g:each in="${billing.rows}" status="i" var="row">
<span class="${cssClass}">${row.id}</span>
</g:each>
</g:each>
```

for every odd and even billing id you define a different css style. in you main css file you have to define the class even and odd e.g. with a background color. don't know hwo you output structure looks like, so created a sample code.

Comment: Thanks That worked..that looks good but it will be better if i give first set of rows which have same bill id the same color and next set of same bill id's to have other color.i want to alternate two colors between rows with same bill id's..how can i do that.

Comment: its more comfortable to prepare your data in your controller and then pass it to your gsp. in the controller you can use a helper class to store the billing information and the appropriate color. you can check if there are more than one billing with same id and change the color based on e.g. a continuous number within the same billings.

Answer (score 0):

While it might seems like a good idea to show table rows with the same billId value in the same color, this may not be practical. For example, if you have 100 different billId field values, you'll need to find 100 different colors to use for your table rows and each of these colors will need to work well with the table's background/text color.

Even if you can somehow find enough colors, your table is likely to end up looking like an explosion in a paint factory.

A simpler/better solution might be to use a row's `onclick` event to highlight all rows in red (for example) that have the same billId value as the selected row. You'll need to use JavaScript for this.

### Update

The comment below explains that you simply want alternating colors every 5 rows. Try this:

```
<table>

<g:each in="${billings}" status="i" var="billing">

  <tr class="${i % 10 < 5 ? 'rows1' : 'rows2'}">
    <td>${billing.id}</td>

    <!-- Add other <tds> here -->
  </tr>
</g:each>

</table>
```

In CSS you'll need to create classes named `rows1` and `rows2` that define the row styles

Comment: I don have 100 to gether rows.just 5 rows for each bill id and i want to use only 2 colors.first five with one color and other five with other.how can i do that

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
<g:each in="${billings}" status="i" var="billing">
  <set var="cssClass" value"${i < (billings.size()/2) ? 'class1' : 'class2'}"/>
  <g:each in="${billing.rows}" status="i" var="row">
    <span class="${cssClass}">${row.id}</span>
  </g:each>
</g:each>
```

Comment: did you just copy this from hitty5?